# c++ rest sdk http_listener as a network server

Tags: c++, rest, httplistener, casablanca

How to configure http_listener to listen on my ip address so other computers
on the network can send requests to the server ?

```
http_listener listener(L"http://localhsot:9000"); // not working
http_listener listener(L"http://0.0.0.0:9000"); // run time error
http_listener listener(L"http://*:9000");       // run time error
```

I want to use c++ rest sdk as a server on my local network .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://casablanca.codeplex.com/discussions/478976

HENRYTM Answer

Hi I also encountered this problem.
You can solve this by using nginx as proxy on linux. This can also add https feature to your server.
Here is a small version of the needed nginx config file:

```
   server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name localhost;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:12345/;
            proxy_redirect http://localhost:12345/ https://$server_name/;
  }
```

This script redirects all traffic to 12345. Now you just have to listen to

```
   http_listener listener(L"http://localhost:12345");
```

Don't forget to the "support" calls.
Cheers,
Henry

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in casablanca without using a proxy?? I would like to use Casablanca as an embedded http server.

Answer (score 6):

The reason why `http_listener listener(L"http://localhsot:9000");`

isn't working is because "localhost" is spelled wrong.

Once you correct the misspelling, you should be able to point your web browser to 
http://localhost:9000 and you'll receive the request. Test it with a print function.

As mentioned, don't forget to set up the support for the request.

```
Listener.support(methods::GET, std::bind(&HandleGet, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

and the HandleGet function (if GET request)

```
HandleGet(http_request request)
{
   std::wcout << L"Received GET request" << std::endl;
}
```

So after this has been setup, point your web browser to the address, and you should see the output.

Also, you can wrap the `ServerInit.open().wait()` (starts the listening) in a `try/catch` to see why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Being the author, I can highly recommend [Restbed](https://github.com/corvusoft/restbed).  It is an open-source project written in C++11 with the goal of reaching HTTP(s) 1.0-2.0 compliance.

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <restbed>

using namespace std;
using namespace restbed;

void get_method_handler( const shared_ptr< Session >& session )
{
    const auto request = session->get_request( );

    size_t content_length = 0;
    request->get_header( "Content-Length", content_length );

    session->fetch( content_length, [ ]( const shared_ptr< Session >& session,
                                         const Bytes& body )
    {
        fprintf( stdout, "%.*s\n", ( int ) body.size( ), body.data( ) );

        session->close( OK, "Hello, World!", { { "Content-Length", "13" } } );
    } );
}

int main( const int, const char** )
{
    auto resource = make_shared< Resource >( );
    resource->set_path( "/resource" );
    resource->set_method_handler( "GET", get_method_handler );

    auto settings = make_shared< Settings >( );
    settings->set_port( 1984 );
    settings->set_default_header( "Connection", "close" );

    Service service;
    service.publish( resource );
    service.start( settings );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/tree/master/example) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I created an account on dyndns.it and setting my router dynamic dns account with username and password of dynds.it account.
After that server listens on that url :

```
uri_builder uri(L"http://my_account.homepc.it:80/"); 
auto addr = uri.to_string();
http_listener listener(addr);



listener.support(methods::POST, handle_post);

try
{
    listener
        .open()
        .then([&listener](){TRACE(L"\nstarting to listen\n"); })
        .wait();

    while (true);
}
catch (exception const & e)
{
    wcout << e.what() << endl;
}
catch (...)
{
    wcout << "error" << endl;
}
```

and it works from any location(even if i still don't understand how to manage POST from multiple clients at same time!)